# Solr Suggester 5.3 do not return results

Tags: java, php, solr, autosuggest

I am trying to implement auto complete feature using Solr 5.3.0

My Shema:

```
<field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true"   stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
<field name="type"    type="string"   indexed="true"  stored="true"  multiValued="false" />
<field name="name"    type="string"   indexed="true"  stored="true"  multiValued="false" />
<field name="isbn"    type="string"   indexed="true"  stored="true"  multiValued="false" />
<field name="title"    type="string"   indexed="true"  stored="true"  multiValued="false" />
<field name="year"    type="string"   indexed="true"  stored="true"  multiValued="false" />
<field name="pages"    type="int"   indexed="true"  stored="true"  multiValued="false" />
<field name="page"    type="int"   indexed="true"  stored="true"  multiValued="false" />
<field name="family"  type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
<field name="text"    type="doctext"   indexed="true"  stored="true"  multiValued="false" termVectors="true" termPositions="true" termOffsets="true"/>
<field name="alsearch"   type="string"   indexed="true"  stored="true"  multiValued="false" />
```

My Configurations on solrconfig.xml:

```
<searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
<lst name="suggester">
<str name="name">mySuggester</str>
<str name="lookupImpl">FuzzyLookupFactory</str>
<str name="storeDir">suggester_fuzzy_dir</str>>

<str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>

<str name="field">name</str>
<str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">string</str>
<str name="buildOnStartup">true</str>
<str name="buildOnCommit">false</str>    
</lst>
</searchComponent>

<requestHandler name="/suggest" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
 <lst name="defaults">
 <str name="suggest">true</str>
 <str name="suggest.count">10</str>
 <str name="suggest.dictionary">mySuggester</str>
</lst>
<arr name="components">
  <str>suggest</str>
</arr>
```

when i try:
http://localhost:8983/solr/alsearch/suggest?suggest=true&suggest.build=true&suggest.dictionary=mySuggester&wt=xml&suggest.q=marketing

the result is :

```
<response><lst name="responseHeader"><int name="status">0</int><int name="QTime">2633</int></lst><str name="command">build</str><lst name="suggest"><lst name="mySuggester"><lst name="marketing"><int name="numFound">0</int><arr name="suggestions"/></lst></lst></lst></response>
```

what is wrong?

Comment: are you sure, you reloaded the core after the suggester configuration?

Comment: yes, i reloaded the core now. I have to index after the reload?

Comment: If you have already indexed then not required. You are using `<str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">string</str>`, are you sure that `marketing` is present in the data. Did you try for other terms?

Comment: Thanks, now i tried to search for another term and i have found results.

Comment: Mark question answered!!